# How to update GraalVM?

Tags: java, graalvm

GraalVM 21.2 is released https://www.graalvm.org/release-notes/21_2/

I have `graalvm-ce-java11-21.1.0` instance

```
export GRAALVM_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-21.1.0/Contents/Home
```

Can I update it to 21.2 without manually downloading/installing new instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `gu upgrade` and it'll download the new GraalVM and place nearby for you: https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/graalvm-updater/#upgrade-graalvm
It doesn't overwrite the existing installation, but you can switch the `$GRAALVM_HOME` to point to the new location.